# Lahman's Baseball Database - Determine Primary Position

Tags: mysql

I'm using Lahman's Baseball Database and MySQL to determine each player's primary position. The goal is to write a query that will return the playerID and the position at which they played most games. I know that I would probably want a query that looks something like this:

```
select playerID, sum(G)
from fielding
where POS = 'C'
group by playerID
order by sum(G) desc;
```

The above query gathers all the games each player has played as a catcher. What I want to do is take each player and compare the sum of games played at each position and find the maximum value from that.

If you are not familiar with Lahman's Baseball Database here is the download link: http://www.seanlahman.com/baseball-archive/statistics/

Also here is the create table statement for the Fielding table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Fielding` (
  `playerID` varchar(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `yearID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `stint` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `teamID` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lgID` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `POS` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `G` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InnOuts` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PO` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `A` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `E` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DP` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PB` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WP` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SB` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ZR` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`playerID`,`yearID`,`stint`,`POS`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The Fielding table is organized by year. POS is the position, G is for the number of games they played at the that position in the corresponding year. That means there will be multiple entires for some players in the same year. Also, ignore the case when POS = 'OF' as this takes the sum of all games played at LF, CF, and RF in the given year.

The final output should be a row for each distinct player, with columns playerID and primaryPosition.

Comment: Surely the POS is just the position, not the number of games at a given position!! What's stint? Maybe it should come at the end of the covering index.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Strawberry, I have edited the question in regards to POS and G columns. stint is used when a player is traded. When stint is 1 that is the player's first stint in the season, when it's 2 that's the second and so on. It allows you to see the stat line for a player by team, or before and after a trade. However, when determining primary positions it is irrelevant.

Comment: It's just SELECT player_id, MAX(g) ... GROUP BY player_id. To get the corresponding position, just join the fielding table back onto that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**plan**

> 1. create table showing sums of players in all positions
> 2. get maximum sum of positions from this table
> 3. join back to sums to get the corresponding primary position

---

**query**

```
create table psums as 
(
  select playerID, POS, sum(G) as sm
  from Fielding 
  where POS <> 'OF'
  group by playerID, POS 
)
;

select ps.playerID, ps.POS as primaryPosition
from
(
  select playerID, max(sm) mx
  from psums
  group by playerID
) maxs
inner join
psums ps
on  maxs.playerID = ps.playerID
and maxs.mx       = ps.sm
order by ps.playerID
;
```

[ adding limit 10 ]

**output**

```
+-----------+-----------------+
| playerID  | primaryPosition |
+-----------+-----------------+
| aardsda01 | P               |
| aaronha01 | RF              |
| aaronto01 | 1B              |
| aasedo01  | P               |
| abadan01  | 1B              |
| abadfe01  | P               |
| abadijo01 | 1B              |
| abbated01 | 2B              |
| abbeybe01 | P               |
| abbeych01 | P               |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But ... there has to be a more efficient way. I want to avoid creating a new table or view. Also, this query takes a really long time to execute, even with the limit of 10 results. I want to be able to run this on the entire list of players, which is a total of 18,589. The answer you posted would take far too long.

Comment: yeah its a bit slow, however i dont think the limit speeds anything up. it has to evaluate everything before it does the order by, so the [ slow ] speed it takes todo 10 is the same speed itll take todo all. for example in tests just now it takes 46.33 for all records and 49.25 for 10. performance difference will just be due to random io and os usage issues ( effectively the same time for both )

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM fielding x
  JOIN 
     ( 
       SELECT playerid
            , MAX(g) max_g 
         FROM fielding 
        GROUP 
           BY playerid 
     ) y
    ON y.playerid = x.playerid
   AND y.max_g = x.g
 LIMIT 10;
```

...or, more likely...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM 
     ( SELECT playerid,pos,SUM(g) sum_g FROM fielding GROUP BY playerid,pos ) x
  JOIN
     (
       SELECT playerid
            , MAX(sum_g) max_sum_g 
         FROM 
            ( SELECT playerid
                   , pos
                   , SUM(g) sum_g 
                FROM fielding 
               GROUP 
                  BY playerid
                   , pos
            ) n
        GROUP
           BY playerid
     ) y
    ON y.playerid = x.playerid
   AND y.max_sum_g = x.sum_g
 LIMIT 10;
```